# &keyframes animation not working in firefox

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have been asked to figure out why this animation works in chrome but not in firefox, I have little experience with css3 transitions, I prefer jQuery but I have been asked to get to the bottom of it so...
here is the css, I hope its obvious what the html would be, I'm sure the html is fine as it works in chrome so I'm sure its a syntax error or similar.

> edit - please see http://jsfiddle.net/5Uq86/

```
/* the animation */
@keyframes sub-menu-anim                                        {   to {height: 65px;}  }
@-moz-keyframes sub-menu-anim       /* Firefox */               {   to {height: 65px;}  }
@-webkit-keyframes sub-menu-anim    /* Safari and Chrome */     {   to {height: 65px;}  }
@-o-keyframes sub-menu-anim         /* Opera */                 {   to {height: 65px;}  }

/* products menu animation */
@keyframes sub-menu-anim-prod                                       {   to {height: 210px;} }
@-moz-keyframes sub-menu-anim-prod      /* Firefox */               {   to {height: 210px;} }
@-webkit-keyframes sub-menu-anim-prod   /* Safari and Chrome */     {   to {height: 210px;} }
@-o-keyframes sub-menu-anim-prod        /* Opera */                 {   to {height: 210px;} }

/* health menu animation */
@keyframes sub-menu-anim-health                                     {   to {height: 294px;} }
@-moz-keyframes sub-menu-anim-health    /* Firefox */               {   to {height: 294px;} }
@-webkit-keyframes sub-menu-anim-health /* Safari and Chrome */     {   to {height: 294px;} }
@-o-keyframes sub-menu-anim-health      /* Opera */                 {   to {height: 294px;} }

/* applying the animation to the menu */
#primaryNav li.menu-item ul.sub-menu {
    animation:sub-menu-anim 0.5s;
    -moz-animation: sub-menu-anim 0.5s; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: sub-menu-anim 0.5s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-animation: sub-menu-anim 0.5s; /* Opera */
}

#primaryNav li.menu-item ul.sub-menu ul.sub-menu {
    animation:none;
    -moz-animation:none; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation:none !important; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-animation:none; /* Opera */
}

#primaryNav li#menu-item-17 ul.sub-menu {
    animation:sub-menu-anim-prod 0.5s;
    -moz-animation: sub-menu-anim-prod 0.5s; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: sub-menu-anim-prod 0.5s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-animation: sub-menu-anim-prod 0.5s; /* Opera */
}

#primaryNav li#menu-item-229 ul.sub-menu {
    animation:sub-menu-anim-health 0.5s;
    -moz-animation: sub-menu-anim-health 0.5s; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: sub-menu-anim-health 0.5s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-animation: sub-menu-anim-health 0.5s; /* Opera */
}
```

Comment: can you post a fiddle of this working/not working? I've tried to replicate but it seems to work as expected to me.

Comment: hey, please see http://jsfiddle.net/5Uq86/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seemed to be with where you were calling the animation. I changed your CSS selector to do it on the hover (so that the animation happens each time you hover) and made an adjustment to the `-moz-animation` property to include more values, to this:

```
#primaryNav li#menu-item-17:hover > ul.sub-menu {
    animation:sub-menu-anim-prod 0.5s;
    -moz-animation: 0.5s ease 0s normal none 1 sub-menu-anim-prod;
    -webkit-animation: sub-menu-anim-prod 0.5s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-animation: sub-menu-anim-prod 0.5s; /* Opera */
}
```

This seems to work. I have checked it in Firefox and Chrome. I also update other selectors to incorporate what I have done above. Please check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5Uq86/1/) for the rest of the changes.

Comment: works but still not 100% satisfactory as the li.sub-menu items are displayed before the animation completes - so looks off. But still you sorted the initial problem so giving you the big green tick!